# Registering a holtwinter data function in Spotfire through R

Tags: r, forecasting, spotfire, terr

I have to forecast the data using holtwinters forecast. I cannot use direct holtwinter forecast as i need to have bars in forecast which is not possible because the data on which i am forecasting are stacked bars.
So, i need to write a data function using holtwinters in r(terr) and return a table from it and then in turn plot that table as bars.

I simply need to write a holtwinter function in r.

Can anyone help me achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If anything is not clear, please mention in comment. The question is to how to use holtwinter in r scripting in terr.

Comment: I'm sure someone has already done this, no? Maybe [this function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/HoltWinters.html) or [this one](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/stats/html/predict.HoltWinters.html) or perhaps [this thread from stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63250/forecasting-function-r-holt-winters-hw-approach)

Comment: yes.. but i need to know how to implement it in R @scsimon